# Como usar arquivos PHP com página de erro customizada no Web.config

Tags: php, iis, web.config, página-de-erro

Tenho um arquivo chamado `error.php`, ele pega o valor **GET** ou uma variável já definida e exibi os erros em vários idiomas e de todos os tipos.

Eu utilizo o IIS e já tentei no Web.config usar páginas PHP, mas não obtive sucesso, consigo apenas com páginas HTML que não é o meu propósito.

*Como posso usar o arquivo erro.php como página de erro no Web.config?*

**Web.config atual:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
    <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
            <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
                <remove statusCode="401" />
                <error statusCode="401" path="sys\error\401.html responseMode="File" />
                .....
            </httpErrors>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

E eu tentei utilizar da seguinte maneira, mas não funcionou:

```
 <error statusCode="401" path="sys\error.php?number=401" responseMode="File" />
```

Comment: Pessoal desculpa de como está a pergunta, fiz pelo celular mas não consegui como queria...e agora pra editar ele bugou todo o texto... ESTOU CONCERTANDO!

Comment: Ta quase certa a formação, precisa dos 4 espaços e também pular uma linha para separar. Por exemplo depois do `web.config atual:` da um enter :)

Comment: Não funcionou como? Apareceu a página padrão é isso? ou apareceu outro erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que `responseMode="File"` mandar a resposta como se o arquivo fosse um arquivo estático, se você quer "executar ele", não deve usar `\` invertida neste caso e o caminho deve começar do "root" `/` (com barra na frente) assim:

```
<error statusCode="401" path="/sys/error.php?number=401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

Testado no *IIS8 Express*, acredito que não mude no *IIS padrão* e nem na versão 7.

> Nota:
>
> Acredito que os códigos de status não possam ser customizados: *400, 403.9, 411, 414, 500, 500.11, 500.14, 500.15, 501, 503 e 505.*
>
> <sub>https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753103%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396</sub>

<s>Se não der certo tente apenas:</s>

```
<error statusCode="401" path="/sys/error.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

E ao invés de usar `_GET` use a função [`http_response_code()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) (requer php5.4+) faça isto no seu *error.php*:

```
<?php
echo http_response_code();
```

Comment: A página ficou em branco, usando os 2 métodos do _ExecuteURL_

Comment: @Vinicius qual versão do php? Tentou sem o ?number= ?

Comment: A versão do meu PHP é a 5.6.18 a última. Gostaria de usar a 7.0.3 mas não tem suporte pra PDO sqlsrv. Tentei sim sem ele, mas também ficou em branco

Comment: Funcionou pondo `/` no início, muito obrigado! Se puder por favor editar a resposta dizendo que é necessário por `/` no início agradeço :)

Comment: Sobre o `http_response_code();` ele sempre retorna **202**

Comment: @Vinicius qual versão do IIS?

Comment: Acredito que seja a versão 6.0 do IIS, pq aparentemente o 7 não tem suporte para o Windows 10

Comment: @Vinicius obrigado, amanhã eu pesquiso sobre este problema e atualizo, o GET funciona normal?

Comment: Não mano a sua resposta funcionou eu só tive que por `/sys/error.php?number=404` o que mudou é só a **/** no início. O GET funciona normal também

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36536/discussion-between-vinicius-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: @Vinicius fiz o teste com `http_response_code` sempre me retorna 200 (IIS8 express), removi essa parte da resposta.